# Code to print the stack in C only returning "1"

Tags: c, security, stack

I'm learning about security. Here is some sample code I've been given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *j; /* use to dump the stack in function cat */

/* Strings to be copied into buffer in function cat */
char str1[] = "";
char str2[] = "";

int main() {

void cat(int *parm) {
   char buffer[8];

   /* Dump the stack for function cat */
   for (j=buffer; j<((char *)&parm); j++)
      printf("%p: 0x%x\n", j, *(unsigned char *)j);

   /* copy str1 followed by str2 into buffer */
   /* note that a \0 remains between str1 and str2 in buffer */
   strcpy(buffer, str1);
   strcpy(&buffer[strlen(str1)+1], str2);

}

   int *arg; /* dummy argument for call to function cat */
   int x;
   x = 0;
   cat(arg);
   x = 1;
   printf("%d\n",x);

}
```

I'm compiling with GCC. All I'm getting is "1" though. Any ideas why?

Also, my goal is to eventually get the program to print out "0", and achieve this by only adding code to cat(). I can't change anything already there, just add. Any help to get me started in the right direction.

Comment: Functions inside functions? That's a bit weird - who gave you this code?

Comment: You better hope the compiler hasn't optimized anything.

Comment: I got this code from a professor at my school, but I don't believe he'll answer emails on the weekend

Comment: @Carl Norum - IIRC functions inside functions is a gcc extension

Comment: Sure - I'm just surprised someone actually did it.

Comment: Wonder what is the result from `printf("buffer = %p, casted parm = %p\n", buffer, (char*)&parm);`?

Comment: buffer = 0x7ffff8b04ca0, casted parm = 0x7ffff8b04c98

Answer (score 1):

> I'm compiling with GCC. All I'm getting is "1" though. Any ideas why?

We can see

```
   x = 1;
   printf("%d\n",x);
```

so that is likely the *only* print statement actually being run.

So I infer that `for (j=buffer; j<((char *)&parm); j++)` is never entered.
Which is a bit weird. I'd expect a downward growing stack, so I'd expect the address of the parameter `parm` to be higher than `buffer`.

What machine are you using?
Try printing the values of buffer and &parm, e.g.

```
void cat(int *parm) {
   char buffer[8];

   printf("buffer=%p\n", buffer);
   printf("&parm=%p\n", &parm);
```

...

Comment: buffer=0x7fffcbf8cb00
&parm=0x7fffcbf8caf8
1

Comment: anything I can do to fix how my stack grows?

Comment: No recommendations. I'm running the newest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have some weird compiler flags?

Comment: Normal Ubuntu installation. Just compiling with -Wall.

Comment: @user1248092 The values of buffer and &parm are not what I would expect for an x86/ARM. I assume you are running on a normal x86 machine? What is the command line you are using to compile the program?

Comment: Yes a 64 bit machine. gcc test.c -o test

Comment: @user1248092 I've just run it on my Mac, compiling from from within XCode, or from the command line, and I get the same result, only 1. My gcc is quite old, gcc-4.2.1. I wonder if that is the cause? (I need to go to sleep, it is past 4am here, sorry)

Comment: @user1248092 what does gcc --version print?

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Your trampoline code compiles fine for me:
gcc -o tramp tramp
on  Linux 2.6.24,
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1

My output:

jim@jim-HP ~
$ cc tramp.c -o tramp

jim@jim-HP ~
$ tramp

```
0x28ccf0: 0x4
0x28ccf1: 0x6f
0x28ccf2: 0x24
0x28ccf3: 0x61
0x28ccf4: 0x6
0x28ccf5: 0x6f
0x28ccf6: 0x24
0x28ccf7: 0x61
0x28ccf8: 0x28
0x28ccf9: 0xcd
0x28ccfa: 0x28
0x28ccfb: 0x0
0x28ccfc: 0xa8
0x28ccfd: 0x11
0x28ccfe: 0x40
0x28ccff: 0x0
1
```

Is that what you meant by 'all I got was 1'?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results with gcc 4.6.2 on 64-bit Linux, whether I use native 64-bit compilation or make a 32-bit executable with `-m32`.  Looking at the assembly code produced by `gcc -S`, the issue is that gcc is making a local copy of `parm` in the stack frame of `cat`, with an address lower than `buffer`.

Now in the case of 64-bit code gcc has no choice on that point, since the argument is passed in a CPU register, and there would be no other way to give `parm` an address for the `&parm` operation.  However, for some reason gcc makes a local copy of `parm` even in 32-bit code, where it would have a perfectly fine copy already in the stack.

In any case I think all this is a side issue for your homework: you can get a better upper bound for the loop by passing something useful in `parm` and then use `parm` instead of `&parm` at the loop bound in `cat`.